# If Eve can guess all strings with small probability then she can guess a particular element with high probability using Bayes' Theorem.

Tags: probability, information-theory, bayes-theorem

I am trying to understand the following implication :

> If Eve is able to correctly guess, with a small probability, the whole output string $A=(A_1,A_2,\ldots , A_n)$. Using **Bayes' rule** one can then derive the following:
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> &\operatorname{Pr}\left(\text { Eve guesses } A_{1} \ldots A_{n} \text { correctly }\right) \geq \varepsilon  \\
> &\Rightarrow ~\exists i_{0} ~ s.t. ~ \operatorname{Pr}\left(\text { Eve guesses } A_{i_{0}} \mid\right. \text { guesses for } \\
> &\left.A_{1}, \ldots, A_{i_{0}-1} \text { were correct }\right) \geq 1-\delta
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> for some small $\delta>0$.

I am not getting how [Bayes's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem#Statement_of_theorem) is used to get this conclusion, i.e., If Eve can guess all strings with small probability then she can guess a particular element with high probability conditioned that the guess for previous elements was correct.

Can you please help me in understanding the above argument clearly.

*It appeared in [this paper](https://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.140501) or [[1]](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Tehssntzn2acmOXbvpzVVHlzz0SBf-2j/view?usp=sharing) (pg 6)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have access to the full paper, however I have an idea what might be meant. I will assume that the statement is meant for large $n$.

By the definition of conditional probability,
$$ P(\text{Eve guesses } A_{i}∣ \text{ guesses for } A_1,\dots,A_{i-1} \text{ were correct} ) = \frac{P(\text{Eve guesses } A_1,\dots,A_i \text{ correctly})}{P(\text{Eve guesses } A_1,\dots,A_{i-1} \text{ correctly})}. $$
Now denote by $B_i \triangleq P(\text{Eve guesses } A_1,\dots,A_i \text{ correctly})$ and assume to the contrary that for all $i$, it is true that $P(\text{Eve guesses } A_{i}∣ \text{ guesses for } A_1,\dots,A_{i-1} \text{ were correct} ) <1-\delta$. Then,
$$\frac{B_i}{B_{i-1}} <1-\delta \tag{1}\label{1}$$
for all $i$. By definition, $P( \text{Eve guesses } A_1\dots,A_n \text{ correctly} ) = B_n$. Using \eqref{1} multiple times, we deduce that $B_i<(1-\delta)B_{i-1}<(1-\delta)^2B_{i-2}<\dots$ and thus
$$ B_n<(1-\delta)^{n-1}. $$
However, on the other hand, we know that $P(B_n) \geq \epsilon$. Therefore, the contrary assumption leads to a contradiction, whenever $(1-\delta)^{(n-1)}<\epsilon$, or equivalently, $\delta>1-\epsilon^{1/(n-1)}$. And thus the statement is true for all $\delta > 1-\epsilon^{1/(n-1)}$, where the r.h.s is close to $0$ whenever $n$ is large.

Comment: I like your explanation but I have few questions: 1. Are you actually using the Bayes rule or just the definition of conditional probability? 2. Can you help me understand how you got the upper bound on $B_n$ from previous inequality ?

Comment: Thanks! 1. You are right, I am actually just using the definition of conditional probability. I am not quite sure how to use Bayes rule here. I'll add an explanation if something using Bayes rule comes into my mind. 2. Start with $B_1\leq 1$, then use the inequality to conclude that $B_2<(1-\delta)B_1 \leq (1-\delta)$. Next, use $B_3<(1-\delta)B_2 < (1-\delta)(1-\delta)$, where we plugged in the previous result on $B_2$. Then, continue with $B_4,\dots$ until you reach $B_n$. Hope that explains!